# Instagram Stories not Loading on Samsung S8

Tags: instagram

This is a new Galaxy S8 with Android 8.0.0 and the up to date version of Instagram installed. When I click on one of the stories, they just don't load. I get this screen:

[image: Reload button]

When I click the reload button, nothing happens.

I find it rather unlikely that this is really a bug in the app.

I already tried rebooting the phone and reinstalling the app, both to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it is the setting of the clock on the device. The automatic mode was switched off and I had the time set manually. This seems to interfere with Instagrams ability to determine the age of a story.

So switching on automatic mode for the clock solved the problem.